# A holomorphic function which vanishes at a point can be written as a product

Tags: complex-analysis

This is from a proof in a textbook but the authors don't justify this particular step (restated):

Let $f(z)$ be a holomorphic function in some disk $D$ with $f(a) = 0$ for some $a \in D$.
Then there exists a holomorphic function $g(z)$ on $D$ such that $f(z) = (z-a)g(z)$. Why?

Comment: $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (z-a)^n; f(a)=0\rightarrow f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(z-a)^n=(z-a)\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n (z-a)^{n-1}$

Comment: This is a fundamental fact about holomorphic functions (it's certainly false for more general functions), and so I imagine that that fact is stated and proved earlier in that textbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f$ is holomorphic around $a$, it equals its own Taylor series at $a$. Since $f(a)=0$, the $(x-a)^0$ or constant term is zero. Dividing the Taylor series by $(x-a)$, then, yields the necessary $g(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)/(x-a)$ has a singularity at $x=a$, but that singularity is removable.  Removing it gives you $g$.